# Pugixml C++ parsing XML

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I am a newbie in pugixml. Consider I have XML given [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/colored/942a03e7a3774ea006b5bfaf66519f63). I want to get value of `Name` and `Roll` of Every Student. The code below only find the tag but not the value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pugixml.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::string xml_mesg = "<data> \
    <student>\
       <Name>student 1</Name>\
       <Roll>111</Roll>\
    </student>\
    <student>\
        <Name>student 2</Name>\
        <Roll>222</Roll>\
    </student>\
    <student>\
        <Name>student 3</Name>\
        <Roll>333</Roll>\
    </student>\
</data>";
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    doc.load_string(xml_mesg.c_str());
    pugi::xml_node data = doc.child("data");
    for(pugi::xml_node_iterator it=data.begin(); it!=data.end(); ++it)
    {
        for(pugi::xml_node_iterator itt=it->begin(); itt!=it->end(); ++itt)
            std::cout << itt->name() << " " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the output of Name and Roll for each student. How can I modify above code? Also, if one can refer [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/942a03e7a3774ea006b5bfaf66519f63)(press Test),  I can directly write xpath which is supported by pugixml. If so, how can I get the values I seek using Xpath in Pugixml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@Cornstalks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287251/cornstalks) for the insight of using xpath in pugixml. I used `child_value` given [here](http://cdn.rawgit.com/zeux/pugixml/v1.5/docs/manual/access.html#manual.access.nodedata). The code of mine was thus:

```
    for(pugi::xml_node_iterator it=data.begin(); it!=data.end(); ++it)
    {
        for(pugi::xml_node_iterator itt=it->begin(); itt!=it->end(); ++itt)
            std::cout << itt->name() << " " << itt->child_value() << " " << std::endl;
    }
```

I could also use xpath as [@Cornstalks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287251/cornstalks) suggested thus making my code as:

```
pugi::xml_document doc;
doc.load_string(xml_mesg.c_str());
pugi::xpath_query student_query("/data/student");

pugi::xpath_query name_query("Name/text()");
pugi::xpath_query roll_query("Roll/text()");

pugi::xpath_node_set xpath_students = doc.select_nodes(student_query);
for (pugi::xpath_node xpath_student : xpath_students)
{
    // Since Xpath results can be nodes or attributes, you must explicitly get
    // the node out with .node()
    pugi::xml_node student = xpath_student.node();

    pugi::xml_node name = student.select_node(name_query).node();
    pugi::xml_node roll = student.select_node(roll_query).node();

    std::cout << "Student name: " << name.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "        roll: " << roll.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with just Xpath:

```
pugi::xpath_query student_query("/data/student");

pugi::xpath_query name_query("Name/text()");
pugi::xpath_query roll_query("Roll/text()");

pugi::xpath_node_set xpath_students = doc.select_nodes(student_query);
for (pugi::xpath_node xpath_student : xpath_students)
{
    // Since Xpath results can be nodes or attributes, you must explicitly get
    // the node out with .node()
    pugi::xml_node student = xpath_student.node();

    pugi::xml_node name = student.select_node(name_query).node();
    pugi::xml_node roll = student.select_node(roll_query).node();

    std::cout << "Student name: " << name.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "        roll: " << roll.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this but how can I change my code so that it gets the value I desire?

Comment: Just put my code right after the line `doc.load_string(xml_mesg.c_str());`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason why you are getting the "tags/nodes" instead of their values is because you are using the name() function instead of value(). Try replacing your itt->name() with itt->value() instead. 
I found some good documentation about accessing document data [here](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/access.html)

Comment: Some more good documentation [here](http://cdn.rawgit.com/zeux/pugixml/v1.5/docs/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop change the following line to get the values like :
student1 and 111 and so on...

```
std::cout << itt.text().get() << " " << std::endl;
```